# Processing detecct whether mouse is inside a bouncing circle when clicked

Tags: processing, mouseclick-event

Trying to determine whether the mouse has been clicked within a certain ball and when it is clicked I want to display text that relates to that specific ball, this is what I have so far any help would be appreciated.

```java
    int rad = 60;        // Width of the shape
float xpos1, ypos1;    // Starting position of shape    
float xspeed = 4;  // Speed of the shape
float yspeed = 4;  // Speed of the shape
int xdirection = 1;  // Left or Right
int ydirection = 1;  // Top to Bottom
boolean overBox1 = false;
void setup() 
{
  size(1200, 800);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(30);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  // Set the starting position of the shape
  xpos1 = width/2;
  ypos1 = height/2;
}

void draw() 
{

  background(102);

  circleone();

}
void circleone()
{
 xpos1 = xpos1 + ( xspeed * xdirection );
 ypos1 = ypos1 + ( yspeed * ydirection );
  if (xpos1 > width-rad || xpos1 < rad) {
    xdirection *= -1;
  }
  if (ypos1 > height-rad || ypos1 < rad) {
    ydirection *= -1;
  }
 ellipse(xpos1, ypos1, rad, rad);

}

 void mouseClick()
 {
   if (overCircle(xpos1,ypos1,rad)==true)
   {
     println("YO");     
   }

 }
 boolean overCircle(float x, float y, int radius) {
  float disX = x - mouseX;
  float disY = y - mouseY;
  if (sqrt(sq(disX) + sq(disY)) <radius) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: in `overCircle` try `if(mouseX<(x+radius) && mouseX>(x-radius)) { if(mouseY<(y+radius) && mouseY >(y-radius)){ return true; } }` _nested if_ . This is from the top of my head, I cannot try it yet, If this doesn't work, I'll be able to help you in about 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This logic seems overcomplicated:

```
float disX = x - mouseX;
float disY = y - mouseY;
if (sqrt(sq(disX) + sq(disY)) <radius)
```

You could just use the `dist()` function instead:

```
return dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < radius;
```

Then if you want to display some text when the ball is clicked, you're going to have to add more than a `println()` statement. You might set a `boolean` variable to `true`, and then in the `draw()` function you'd check that variable and draw something to the screen when it's true.

If you're trying to get many clickable balls on the screen, then you might think about [creating classes](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) that represent a ball and putting your logic in there.

But you haven't really asked a question. You've posted some code, haven't told us what you expect it to do, what it does instead, or how those two things are different. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you'll have much better luck if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire project and ask a specific question about a specific line of code. Good luck.